# Playing 'aes-256-ctr' encrypted DASH stream with FFMPEG/FFPLAY

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to play that stream with following command `ffplay  -allowed_extensions ALL -loglevel debug -decryption_key "***" -encryption_scheme aes-256-ctr  https://***` but I receive following output:

```
 Error when loading first fragment, playlist 0
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f6a60647600] Statistics: 55123 bytes read, 0 seeks
****/stream.mpd: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Is it possible to do it at all?